# Internet Explorer 6 and Opacity

Tags: css, internet-explorer, opacity

This isn't a pressing issue, but everything that I've read indicates that these CSS opacity rules should work in Internet Explorer 6:

```
.videos img {
    zoom: 1;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.videos a.video img {
    opacity: 0.5;
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
}
.videos a.video:hover img {
    opacity: 1.0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
}
```

I have created [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sonnysavage/APQPz/) to share the code. I am testing using [IETester](http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage) on Windows 7, and the technique works in IE 7-9, but not IE 6.

Comment: It works for me. Consider using IE6 that runs "natively".

Comment: @duri - How do I accomplish that?

Comment: Works fine for me in IE6 using IETester... The jsfiddle demo doesn't work for you?

Comment: @WesleyMurch - It does not work for me in IETester. Maybe something to do with Windows 7?

Comment: I'm on Win7 too.. when I hover the images, the opacity kicks in to 100.

Comment: @WesleyMurch - It's always at 100 for me on my machine. I guess I should delete this post.

Comment: @Sonny I downloaded Windows Virtual PC + Windows XP mode so I can run IE6 on virtualised XP. However, as others report that it works for them on W7, I'd try running IETester as administrator. From the IETester homepage: *"CSS Filters are not working correctly in user mode : A solution is to launch IETester as admin user and CSS Filters will work."*

Comment: @duri - Post that as an answer, and I will accept it

Comment: Gosh. IE6? Opacity? Hehehe.  :-D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, it seems we've found the solution. IETester is not fully reliable; in this particular case, filters didn't work because OP didn't run IETester as administrator.

It's always better to use "native" versions of IE, for example IE running in virtual machine.